# postgresql statement_timeout behavior

Tags: postgresql

To avoid long running queries I want to implement statement_time for certain users.

```
pgdb=> alter user user1 set statement_timeout=600;
ALTER ROLE
pgdb=> select * from pg_user where usename = 'user1';
  usename  |  usesysid  | usecreatedb | usesuper | userepl | usebypassrls |  passwd  | valuntil |              useconfig
-----------+------------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 user1 | 2538084332 | f           | f        | f       | f            | ******** |          | {statement_timeout=600}
(1 row)
```

Logged into PSQL as user1, running very short queries comes back but most of the queries (which will complete in few seconds without statement_timeout limit) are timing out, even though the statement_timeout is set to 180s.

```
pgdb=> select count(*) from schema.tablea limit 10; -- huge table timeout
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
Time: 184.118 ms
imaods=> explain select count(*) from schema.tablea limit 10;
                                                                                       QUERY PLAN

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------
 Limit  (cost=1906894.11..1906894.12 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Finalize Aggregate  (cost=1906894.11..1906894.12 rows=1 width=8)
         ->  Gather  (cost=1906893.89..1906894.10 rows=2 width=8)
               Workers Planned: 2
               ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=1905893.89..1905893.90 rows=1 width=8)
                     ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using idx1 on tablea  (cost=0.57..1828328.86 rows=31026013 width=0)
(6 rows)

pgdb=> select count(*) from tableb;
 count
-------
   260
(1 row)

Time: 0.672 ms
pgdb=> select count(*) from tableb a, tableb b;
 count
-------
 67600
(1 row)
Time: 4.405 ms

pgdb=> select count(*) from tableb a, tableb b, tableb c;  -- timeout
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout

pgdb=> explain select count(*) from tableb a, tableb b, tableb c;                                                                 
                                           QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=264536.10..264536.11 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..220596.10 rows=17576000 width=0)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..878.85 rows=67600 width=0)
               ->  Seq Scan on tableb a  (cost=0.00..16.60 rows=260 width=0)
               ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.90 rows=260 width=0)
                     ->  Seq Scan on tableb b  (cost=0.00..16.60 rows=260 width=0)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.90 rows=260 width=0)
               ->  Seq Scan on tableb c  (cost=0.00..16.60 rows=260 width=0)
(8 rows)

pgdb=> explain analyze select count(*) from tableb a, tableb b, tableb c;
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
pgdb=> explain select count(*) from tableb a, tableb b;
                                               QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1047.85..1047.86 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..878.85 rows=67600 width=0)
         ->  Seq Scan on tableb a  (cost=0.00..16.60 rows=260 width=0)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.90 rows=260 width=0)
               ->  Seq Scan on tableb b  (cost=0.00..16.60 rows=260 width=0)
(5 rows)

pgdb=> explain select count(*) from tableb;
                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=17.25..17.26 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Seq Scan on tableb  (cost=0.00..16.60 rows=260 width=0)
(2 rows)
```

Does statement_timeout go by estimated time or by the actual execution time. Going by explain plans, looks like its taking estimated time into consideration and not executing the query if it thinks its estimated time exceeds statement_timeout. Is this expected behavior or am I missing something? My understanding is it should run the query and timeout when the actual execution time exceeds the timeout limit.

Comment: "even though the statement_timeout is set to 180s."  No, it is set to 600ms.  What on earth makes you think it is set to 180s?

Comment: I was playing with different values, so mixed up there. I was thinking it is secs, i should rtfm, its in ms. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it goes by the actual execution time. The timer starts running when the statement starts executing. How else would you explain that you have for 180 seconds until the query is canceled?

PostgreSQL does not estimate execution time directly. The cost measurements are somewhat artificial, with the rough guideline that 1 corresponds to the time to read one 8kB page from disk during a sequential scan.